# How to find suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs, bower-install

I get the following error when I run bower. How do I resolve it?

```css
$ bower install --save angular-touch
bower angular-touch#*           cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#1.4.6
bower angular-touch#*         validate 1.4.6 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#*
bower angular#1.4.6             cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.6
bower angular#1.4.6           validate 1.4.6 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.6
bower angular#~1.3              cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.19
bower angular#~1.3            validate 1.3.19 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3
bower angular#>= 1.0.8          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.6
bower angular#>= 1.0.8        validate 1.4.6 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.8
bower angular#>=1.2.26 <=1.5    cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.6
bower angular#>=1.2.26 <=1.5  validate 1.4.6 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.2.26 <=1.5
bower angular#>=1.3.0           cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.6
bower angular#>=1.3.0         validate 1.4.6 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.3.0
bower angular#~1.2.28           cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower angular#~1.2.28         validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.28
bower angular#~1.2.25           cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower angular#~1.2.25         validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.25
bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

My bower.json:

```css
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.4",
    "angular-busy": "~4.1.3",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3",
    "angular-translate": "~2.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
 "bootstrap-toggle": "~2.2.0",
    "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "~1.2.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "jquery": "2.0",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "modernizr": "~2.8.3",
    "moment": "~2.10.0",

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is driving me nuts too.  Looks like I've been down a similar path adding resolutions with no luck.  My dev environment is a mac where npm and bower work fine with no complaints.  It is when I commit my changes and jenkins grabs the code onto an ubuntu server that bower breaks.